# how to delete a specific characters within a column in R?

Tags: r

I have a data file looks like:

```
chr1 2
chr1 7
chr3 9
chr4 88
chr32 300
```

I want to delete the letters from the first column so the output would be:

```
1 2
1 7
3 9
4 88
32 300
```

any suggestion please?(my real data is really huge)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
df <- data.frame(col1=c("chr1","chr2","chr3","chr4","chr32"), col2=c(2,7,9,88,300))
df$col1 <- gsub("chr", "", df$col1)

  col1 col2
1    1    2
2    2    7
3    3    9
4    4   88
5   32  300
```

Comment: @Emily - the size of your data should have no bearing on the ability of `gsub` to work (excepting possibly running out of memory to store your data at all)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub`

```
df1$col1 <- as.numeric(sub("\\D+", '', df1$col1))
df1
#  col1 col2
#1    1    2
#2    1    7
#3    3    9
#4    4   88
#5   32  300
```